# ConstraintLayout — limit views' top vertically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have the following layout contents:

```
 <com.g2pdev.sudoku.ui.widget.NumbersView
        android:id="@+id/numbersView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/actionsLayout" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bannerContainerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/bannerAdContainerHeight"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

/>
```

[image]

Red view is `bannerContainerView`, it has fixed height. I'm afraid that there can be a situation when its' top will overlap `numbersView`, so I want to limit its' top edge to `numbersView`'s bottom. Is it possible?

P.S. `constraintTopToBottomOf` does not work here, because if there's enough space, it will center the view vertically.

Comment: *it has fixed height* - does it have to be fixed in size?

Answer (score 0):

Update `NumbersView`'s constraint like below:

```
<com.g2pdev.sudoku.ui.widget.NumbersView
    android:id="@+id/numbersView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bannerContainerView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/actionsLayout" />
```

Comment: @int_32, Have you checked this?